# Error in java when adding attributes and trying to insert code with right click

Tags: java

I  need to make a java program for my master. we have been taught very little but they already gave us an assignment. in this assignment I need to make a list of students

i started with a class to create the attributes for each student and made a constructor. I need to add now setters and getters but I hear the 'error' sound and nothing happens when i do right click and choose insert code.

The only error I have is that when i added the attributes i got an error that variables are never read. I did the steps exactly as my teacher has them in his project. when i clicked on that error i had 2 options. one to untick the unused option ( which i did -not sure though if correct, but i don't know how to reverse) or to make the variable final, but i need to edit so i cannot have them final..

Is it possible that this error is the one not allowing me to proceed by adding setters and getters?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acehC.png)

Comment: Please see [mcve], then [edit] your question accordingly. Include the **relevant** parts of your code, and error messages as WELL FORMATTED and INDENTED TEXT in your question.

Comment: Remember: we only have what you give to us to help you. A lot of explanations and screen shot with almost no meaningful content ... just don't achieve that. Note that this could also be some sort of problem with your editor/IDE ... so A) include such information in your question and B) maybe try some other IDE/editor in the meantime.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

seems its resolved. i added manually the first getter setter and then i was able to add the rest with right click insert code. moreover now the initial error disappeared.